# How to deliver a struct which contain an array to driverkit by call driverkit function from swift code?

Tags: arrays, swift, structure, driverkit

I declare a structure type in swift, name as CmdStruct

```
struct CmdStruct {
    var cmd:[UInt8]
    init() {
        cmd = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:16)
    }
}
```

In the case that the connection has been obtained.
In `sendCmd` function, declare a variable which name as `input` which type of `CmdStruct`.
After set data to `input`, call a DriverKit function `IOConnectCallStructMethod`.

Here xcode shows a warning tip for the parameter 'input' for call `IOConnectCallStructMethod`:

> <Forming 'UnsafeRawPointer' to a variable of type 'CmdStruct'; this is
> likely incorrect because 'CmdStruct' may contain an object reference.>

```
func sendCmd() {
    var ret:kern_return_t = kIOReturnSuccess
    var input = cmdStruct()
    var output:[UInt8] = [UInt8](repeating:0, count: 16)
    var inputSize = MemoryLayout<CmdStruct>.size  // print value 8
    var outputSize = output.count // print value 16

    input.cmd[0] = 0x12
    input.cmd[1] = 0x34

    ret = IOConnectCallStructMethod(Connection, selector, &input, inputSize, &output, &outputSize)
}
```

In C file, driverkit function `ExternalMethod` will receive the parameter from swift side.
And check the value of input->cmd[0] and input->cmd[1] in console. However, the values are not the expected 0x12 and 0x34.

```
struct CmdStruct
{
    uint8_t cmd[16];
};

kern_return_t myTest::ExternalMethod(uint64_t selector, IOUserClientMethodArguments* arguments, const IOuserClientMethodDispatch* dispatch, OSObject* target, void* reference) 
{
    int i = 0;
    CmdStruct* input = nullptr;

    if (arguments == nullptr) {
        ret = KIOReturnBadArgument;
    }

    if (arguments->structureInput != nullptr) {
        input = (CmdStruct*)arguments->structureInput->getBytestNoCopy();
    }

    /*
    Here to print input->cmd[0] and input->cmd[1] data to console.
    */
}
```

I expect that the correct value of input will be show on the driverkit side.
I'm not sure which part is wrong.
Here, I list some factors that may lead to incorrect value.

1. How to fix the warning tip for parameter 'input' when call `IOConnectCallStructMethod` in swift.
2. I get the `inputSize` value 8 by using `MemoryLayout<CmdStruct>.size`. But this structure contains a 16 bytes array. How to get the correct struct size in swift
3. In C file side, using (CmdStruct*)arguments->structureInput->getBytestNoCopy() to transform data to C struct is correct?

Comment: I fixed this issue .
I create a bridge-header-file and import the header file that the contains structure.
And set the bridge header file path at the follow setting.
"target" > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - General > Objective-C Bridging Header.

Comment: If you've solved it, you should add that as an answer, not as a comment